# How to see __vfptr in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I knew we can see `__vfptr` in VS, but why vscode did not support this?
Is it possible to increase the debugging parameters or modify the settings?

Answer (score 1):

VS Code filters it out, presumably because it is fairly useless. You can view it in the gdb console by typing

```
-exec print <expression>
```

For example

```
-exec print *this
$1 = (Z) {_vptr.Z = 0x555555754d80 <vtable for Z+16>, a = 42}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is really useful.